# Is there a good blockchain explorer like blockchain.info available for bitcoin cash?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I usually use www.blockchain.info for bitcoin if I want to get information about:

- a specific address (transactions, balance...)
- a specific transaction (source and target address, amount, fees, etc.)
- number of unconfirmed transactions on the network

Is there a similar site for bitcoin cash? Google was not very helpful because it gave me lots of results applicable only  to bitcoin and not bitcoin cash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/). It is a blockchain explorer for both Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash.

Comment: Thanks. This covers the first two of my points, cant find unconfirmed transactions though. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Isn't [this](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/mempool/transactions) what you're looking for?

Comment: I am not sure. https://blockchain.info/de/unconfirmed-transactions shows me conveniently the exact number of unconfirmed transactions at the current time. On your link I do not see it, but maybe I am just unable to look properly?

Comment: However, I just found this: https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/uahf/#24h
So, together with your link above, I have everything I need now. Thank you!